# graniteds-tutorial-data using GraniteDS 3.0.1 error

Tags: apache-flex, maven, graniteds

I run the following command for the example graniteds-tutorial-data in the GraniteDS 3.0.1 GA github repo, but get the error trace given at the bottom of this post,

`mvn clean install asciidoctor:process-asciidoc -Dserver=ejb -Dclient=flex`

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data-client-flex:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Documents and Settings\463072\FreshSpaceJuno\graniteds-tutorial-data\client-flex\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:4.2-beta or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved:
com.adobe.flex.compiler:saxon9:jar:4.5.1.21328, com.adobe.flex.compiler:xalan:jar:4.5.1.21328: Could not transfer artifact com.adobe.flex.compiler:saxon9:jar:4.5.1.21328 from/to flex-mojos-plugin-repository (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/): GET request of: com/adobe/flex/compiler/saxon9/4.5.1.21328/saxon9-4.5.1.21328.jar from flex-mojos-plugin-repository failed: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 5024396; received: 3576621 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: swf @ line 17, column 16
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Any help on how to resolve this will be really appreciated. I am trying to port my application with the GraniteDS 2.0.3 to the latest 3.0.1. Also, are there any examples of a Flex EJB example using GraniteDS 3.0.1?

This is the log after I made the change you suggested.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data-server-model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data instead of org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent, please verify your project structure @ line 28, column 13
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data-client-flex:swf:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data instead of org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-client-flex, please verify your project structure @ line 9, column 13
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-client-flex:3.0.1.GA, C:\Documents and Settings\463072\.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-client-flex\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-client-flex-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 67, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for com.adobe.flex.framework:spark:swc must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'theme'. @ org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-client-flex:3.0.1.GA, C:\Documents and Settings\463072\.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-client-flex\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-client-flex-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 33, column 20
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.graniteds:granite-client-flex:swc must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'internal'. @ org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-client-flex:3.0.1.GA, C:\Documents and Settings\463072\.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-client-flex\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-client-flex-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 49, column 20
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data-server-ejb:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data instead of org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-server-ejb, please verify your project structure @ line 28, column 13
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-server-base:3.0.1.GA, C:\Documents and Settings\463072\.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-server-base\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-server-base-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 37, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin is missing. @ org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-server-base:3.0.1.GA, C:\Documents and Settings\463072\.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-server-base\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-server-base-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 84, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin is missing. @ org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-server-base:3.0.1.GA, C:\Documents and Settings\463072\.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-server-base\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-server-base-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 46, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] GraniteDS Data Tutorial - Server Model
[INFO] GraniteDS Data Tutorial - Flex Client
[INFO] GraniteDS Data Tutorial - EJB Server
[INFO] GraniteDS Data Tutorial

[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building GraniteDS Data Tutorial - Server Model 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

.
.
.

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar


[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ tutorial-data-server-model ---

.
.
.
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-manager/1.9.1/plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.jar

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\463072\FreshSpaceJuno\graniteds-tutorial-data\server-model\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ tutorial-data-server-model ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Documents and Settings\463072\FreshSpaceJuno\graniteds-tutorial-data\server-model\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tutorial-data-server-model ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ tutorial-data-server-model ---
Downloading: http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.12.4/surefire-booter-2.12.4.pom
Downloading: http://dl.bintray.com/graniteds/tutorial-dependencies/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.12.4/surefire-booter-2.12.4.pom
.
.
[INFO] Installing C:\Documents and Settings\463072\FreshSpaceJuno\graniteds-tutorial-data\server-model\pom.xml to C:\Documents and Settings\463072\.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-data-server-model\1.0-SNAPSHOT\tutorial-data-server-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- asciidoctor-maven-plugin:0.1.4:process-asciidoc (default-cli) @ tutorial-data-server-model ---
Downloading: http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.pom
Downloading: http://dl.bintray.com/graniteds/tutorial-dependencies/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/maven-plugin-api-2.0.pom
.
.
.
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/graniteds/granite-client-flex45-advanced/3.0.1.GA/granite-client-flex45-advanced-3.0.1.GA.swc (366 KB at 97.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] GraniteDS Data Tutorial - Server Model ............ SUCCESS [7:41.452s]
[INFO] GraniteDS Data Tutorial - Flex Client ............. FAILURE [1:18.299s]
[INFO] GraniteDS Data Tutorial - EJB Server .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] GraniteDS Data Tutorial ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9:08.939s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 23 12:00:48 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tutorial-data-client-flex: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data-client-flex:swf:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.adobe.flex.framework:framework:zip:configs:4.5.1.21328 from/to flex-mojos-repository (http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/): Checksum validation failed, expected 410a3bcaceb1ea1960b2521818dc7ab9fac35aef but is 5359ccaf2d93e09ff2ec6fffe0648c611f42314b -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :tutorial-data-client-flex
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try renaming temporarily your .m2 to .m2.bak so we can make sure that this is not just an issue with your local repository?

> are there any examples of a Flex EJB example using GraniteDS 3.0.1?

Yes, the one you are trying to launch.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Franck. Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question with the error log I get after your suggested change. Also I was pointing to JDK 1.5.0 which I have changed to 7 now.